# Broken spark plug: safe piston?

Tags: sparkplugs, lpg

I have a broken Spark plug in a 2SZFE engine. Oil level is not changing. Does it means the piston is safe?

There’s a spark plug part in the first cylinder because previous owner chose a low cost model not adapted to higher temperature of lpg. There’s a sealing problem on exhaust but not on admission.

The cylinder head might be damaged, but since there’s no specific sound (the engine can run on 3 cylinder) and the oil colour doesn’t change and the oil level doesn’t change, is it safe to assume the cylinder or piston ring don’t need to be replaced ?

Comment: Why don't you just fix the problem now, before it gets worse over time?

Comment: @kokobill the repair shop want to make me an additional 150€ for inspection of the piston while a more expansive repair shop don’t think it’s required.

Comment: The problem is that a piston with a scratch in the crown from the bits of broken plug bouncing around will work just fine - until the day when it breaks into two pieces, one of which comes out of the side of the engine block. It's your call whether you want to pay 150€ "insurance" against that.

Comment: @alephzero I am wondering if it is possible the broken spark part could just get aspirated in the exhaust poppet valve by just breaking at the right moment. I have an insurrance on mechanical damages. But it only pays repairs if the engine can’t run anymore (since the engine can work on 3 cylinder this isn’t the case here).

Comment: Have you seen the bit of spark plug on a bore scope?

Comment: @SteveMatthews I am afraid the cylinder head needs to be unmounted in order to see something.

Comment: You can definitely get a bore scope down the spark plug hole.

Comment: @SteveMatthews the toyota repair shop I went to proposed to unmount the cylinder head directly in only 2h30 (but in taking more than 100€ per labour hour so taking almost 300€ for the operation). The second repair shop (which is independent) offer 48€ per T2 labour hour but **want me pay 150€ for the bore scope inspection**. That’s why I don’t see that much benefits.

Comment: This site isn't for shopping advice but you can buy a bore scope yourself that plugs into your smart phone for about 15 minutes worth of repair shop time.  Have they compression tested it?

Comment: @SteveMatthews about compression : as I wrote on the question, there’s no problem on fuel admission, but there’s a problem on exhaustion.

Comment: Whats the compression test reading compared to the other cylinders?

Comment: @SteveMatthews 12 bars in all other cylinders. absolutely no compression in the damaged cylinder.

Comment: Then that tells you everything you need to know; pull the cylinder head off.  After 3,000km, it isn't safe to assume any of it will be serviceable including the block itself.

Comment: No compression in the damaged cylinder? It's toast.

Comment: @motosubatsu especially since I didn’t run without the spark. The broken spark plug was still fixed correctly in the engine. Only a tiny part on top of the engine was broken. So if there’s no compression, it’s because something else is broken, but not the spark plug.

Comment: @user2284570 which bit of the spark plug broke off?

Comment: @motosubatsu a special tool is required to unswrew the plugs so I can’t tell exactly. but according to Toyota it’s just a part of the top Electrode which broke off as previous owner (born in 1995) used low cost models which aren’t designed to resists higher burning temperatures of lpg. He also followed manufacturer’s recomendations for heat range instead of taking a colder design for the lpg tranformed engine.

Comment: if it's part of the electrode that's broken off then unless you got *extremely* lucky and it exited right out through the exhaust valve it's going to have done some damage inside the cylinder. Hence the loss of compression, then engine is likely uneconomical to repair - best option at this point IMO is a straight swap for another. €200-300 for a complete unit on ebay and swap the lot. Depending on labor rates you should be able to get the lot done for less than €1000

Comment: @motosubatsu got the answer. Top of piston is damaged because it repeateadly thump the exhaust valve, I have no idea if it will resists if presure come again in the cylinder. Found how to get the job done for 48€ per labour hour. But it seems to be difficult to find a `2SZFE` engine manufactured after 2004 (euro ⅳ standard) in good shape below 500€. **What are the differences between a`2SZFE`manuactured before 2005 and a`2SZFE`manufactured after 2004 ? Is it just the ᴇᴄᴜ or are there other additional equipments?**. I don’t want an emission standard downgrade (the car was manufactured in 2007).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really assume *anything* regarding the state of the internals until you get it open and inspected.

If the engine has been run for any length of time without spark there could be significant damage to the piston and ring from being repeatedly covered in unburnt fuel. And of course any impacts with bits of the broken plug (even relatively small flakes) could have done significant damage also.

Comment: I forgot to say that the engine run on gas. So I don’t think unburnt fuel is a problem. I also wonder if it’s possible the broken spark part could just get aspirated in the exhaust poppet valve by just breaking at the right moment.

Comment: @user2284570 Firstly it doesn't run *exclusively* on lpg - there will have been  a good amount of fuel sloshed through there each time the engine was started. Secondly *if* the bit of the spark plug was small enough to pass through the exhaust valve and *if* it broke off at just the right moment I guess that's possible but I have to say it's not very likely. If any remained (or if it broke off bits of the exhaust valve on it's way past for example) then you'll have had bits of material grinding around inside the cylinder for all the time the engine has been running since.

Comment: Not to mention that there is a chance that the block will be scrap.  The only reasonable course of action is to EITHER; order a gasket set and pull the cylinder head off OR: find a secondhand engine.

Comment: @SteveMatthews Yeah could well be damage to the bore etc. I imagine the first thing a garage will do would be to take a peek with a borescope, if shows a complete mess in there you can at least save the time and money of opening it up and go straight to either a replacement engine or replacement car.

Comment: Worth doing ASAP as otherwise unburned hydrocarbons from whatever fuel is supposed to be being burned in that combustion chamber will kill the catalytic converter.  Also, dumping unburned LPG into a hot exhaust system is a very bad idea.

Comment: @SteveMatthews I had the problem in South Italy. Had to run almost 3000Km to bring the car back in the part of France I am living. Maybe the lamda probe is damaged as result.

Comment: @SteveMatthews agreed... if nothing else unburned LPG will be doing the same to the cat as unburned petrol. Even a closed-loop system won't be able to account for the loss of the spark on the cylinder. I expect that catalytic converter has been having a very hard time!

Comment: @user2284570 You drove **3000Km** after part of the plug broke off? The state of the lambda probe will be the least of your worries. Unless you are an *exceptionally* lucky person the next stop for that engine is going to be the scrapheap.