# What are the technical differences between a 2SZFE engine manuactured before 2005 and a 2SZFE manufactured after 2004?

Tags: engine, toyota, automatic-transmission, yaris, engine-swap

[I need to change my engine](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/61582/#comment108047_61582), I also found a company willing to perform the paperwork for changing to the same engine model.

The car is a Toyota Yaris Luna with semi‑automatic transmission manufactured in december 2007.

My engine model is a`2SZFE`. The problem is the car was built for the euro ⅳ [emission standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_emission_standards#Emission_standards_for_passenger_cars) which was set in 2005. It seems to be far easier and cheaper find a good used engine manufactured under the euro 
ⅲ standard (that is before 2005) and I don’t want a downgrade (there are road restrictions based on emission standard level).

So what are the differences between a `2SZFE` engine manuactured before 2005 and a `2SZFE` manufactured after 2004 ?
Is it just the ECU and/or Gearbox ? Or are there core changes like the engine block which would requires buying a higher price used engine manufactured between 2005‒2008 instead of 1999‒2004 ?

Comment: If "there are road restrictions" doesn't that mean the vehicle will have to pass an emissions *test* (probably every 12 months?) If the "company willing to perform the paperwork" is reputable and legal, they should be able to answer the question better than we can. If not - well, I don't know what SE's official policy regarding questions about illegal activities is, but I know what my *personal* policy is! In the UK you don't need "a company" to do the paperwork for you - all you need to do is submit proof of what you did (e.g. a receipt for the new engine you bought).

Comment: @alephzero - The basis of this question is not about legality, but about the differences between the two engines. It is answerable, without question, so the question is definitely on-topic, IMHO.

Comment: @alephzero the paperwork is about changing the serial numbers on the registration certificate. If an engine requires changing emission level I’ll take an other one which doesn’t. Period !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No changes to the block that I'm aware of - compliance for Euro IV will be determined by the engine map and the catalytic converter in the exhaust.

Swap the block, keep your existing ECU, I'd suggest getting a new catalytic converter as your old one [has probably seen better days](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/61582/broken-spark-plug-safe-piston#comment107683_61583) and you should be good to go.

Life will probably be easier if you can get one that came from an automatic car ideally. I'm not sure what (if any) differences there are between how the auto and manual gearboxes attach on these.

**Update:**

I actually stand corrected - going by part number there are differences 190000J060 is the correct for an '07 Yaris (in Europe at least), an 03-06 car uses part# 190000J050 and a '99-02 uses 190000J020.

While the shortblock is the same between 190000J060 and 190000J050 (and there's been some variations in the head in some years) it looks like the engine mountings are different - presumably to account for the chassis changes between the  P90 and P12 chassis and I could see that meaning it's not just a straight swap.

You *could* get an 190000J050 and essentially cannibalize it for parts to repair the existing engine I suppose - but by the time you've done that you'll easily end up paying more in labor costs then you saved buying the older engine in the first place. Plus you've probably ended up with parts that have done more mileage etc. Getting an intact 190000J060 and swapping the whole unit is going to be the sensible option.

Comment: Ok. Got a phone call to a Toyota specialist. There are three type of engine block for the 2SZFE engine in 2007 alone. So my exact engine type is 190000J060.

Comment: @user2284570 I spoke too soon - looks like the mountings are different between the two chassis. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok. I think I found the real reference for the complete engine 2S‑P72L. I added the exact car reference in the question.